# check for same courseID in the array typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am new to angular. I have question of selecting unique number for particular ID. my array is like this:

```js
[
  {
    CareerPathId: 1,
    CareerPathName: "Agribusiness",
    CourseId: 7,
    CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"
  },
  {
    CareerPathId: 2,
    CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology",
    CourseId: 7,
    CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"
  },
  {
    CareerPathId: 2,
    CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology",
    CourseId: 8,
    CourseName: "Agricultural"
  },
  {
    CareerPathId: 2,
    CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology",
    CourseId: 1,
    CourseName: "Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources"
  }
]
```

I want unique numbers for CourseID. How can i get that. I am using array to store the data.

Answer (score 2):

Using rxjs map and distinct operators

```js
  var arr=[
{CareerPathId: 1, CareerPathName: "Agribusiness", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 8, CourseName: "Agricultural"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 1, CourseName: "Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources"}];

const source = from (arr).pipe(map(item=>item.CourseId));
const distinctValues = source.pipe(distinct());

distinctValues.subscribe(item=>console.log(item));
```

Using ES6 map and set method

```js
  var arr=[
{CareerPathId: 1, CareerPathName: "Agribusiness", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 8, CourseName: "Agricultural"},
{CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 1, CourseName: "Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources"}];

console.log(Array.from(new Set(arr.map(item=>item.CourseId))));
```

Comment: This solution is the proper Angular answer as Angular uses rxjs.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15

```
 _.uniqBy(yourArray, function (item) {
  return item.CourseId;
});
```

Comment: lodash is not really an Angular solution, rxjs is more appropriate.

Comment: That is not an angular problem, it's an array problem, therefore lodash is as suitable as rxjs

Comment: lodash does not come with angular, out of the box, rxjs does.  There are also pure js solutions that work without bringing in an entirely new library.

Comment: Again I'm not questioning which one is best. rxjs is not built for array manipulation on the other hand libraries such as lodash(only 72.5kb in size), underscore(even smaller) are built for that ... and if you consider the amount of time that you operate/manipulate arrays in your day to day task ... you can probably see benefit, of course any tool, library, framework usage is up to each and everyones taste ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set of es6.

```
const arr = [
    {CareerPathId: 1, CareerPathName: "Agribusiness", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
    {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},
    {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 8, CourseName: "Agricultural"},
    {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 1, CourseName: "Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources"}
];

const uniqueValues = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.CourseId))];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **map** and **filter**

```
const courses = [
  {CareerPathId: 1, CareerPathName: "Agribusiness", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},

  {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 7, CourseName: "Agricultural and Environmental"},

  {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 8, CourseName: "Agricultural"},

  {CareerPathId: 2, CareerPathName: "Industrial Power Technology", CourseId: 1, CourseName: "Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources"}
];

const ids: number[] = courses.map((course) => { return course.CourseId; })
.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```